# Insert into embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  userType: { type: String, default: 'user'},
  quizzHistory: [{
    quizzName: String,
    quizzScore: Number
  }]
});
```

my goal is to change document into embedded quizzHistory or insert new one if not exists document in embedded quizzeHistory

I try to set document into embedded quizzHistory :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.session.user['_id'], 'quizzHistory.quizzName': testName},
{ 
    '$set': {
        'quizzHistory.$.quizzName': testName,
        'quizzHistory.$.quizzScore': finalScore
    }
}, {upsert: true},
function(err, upd) {
  console.log("added");
})
```

code above works if there is document in quizzHistory with required _id and quizzHistory.quizzName,but don't pushed new one if there isn't any document.

Is there any way in Mongodb  to change document into embedded collection or insert new one if not exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

```
User.update({ _id: req.session.user['_id'],'quizzHistory.quizzName':testName},
{ 
    $set: {
        "quizzHistory.$.quizzName":testName,
        "quizzHistory.$.quizzScore":finalScore
    }
},
function(err, upd) {
  if(!upd){
        User.update({ _id: req.session.user['_id']},
        { "$addToSet": { quizzHistory:  newScoreData }},function(err,data){
        });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason is because you are using "find and update" you are not handling the condition when the row hasn't been found and create a new document, being said that  you need manage the in a different way like

```
User.update({ _id: req.session.user['_id'], 'quizzHistory.quizzName': testName},
{ 
    '$push': {
        'quizzHistory.quizzName': testName,
        'quizzHistory.quizzScore': finalScore
    }
}, {upsert: true},
function(err, upd) {
  console.log("added");
})
```

Comment: hi @jack.the.ripper thanks for your answer, there is no way to do it without condition?

Comment: which condition? can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: i will do user.find and if it returns empty array i use $push otherwise 
$set

Answer (score 1):

If you want to benefit for all possible plugins and methods added to model and don't want to fight with actual Mongo queries you should first retrieve user object, then push new element to quizzHistory array and do save. Something like below (you need to align that code to your needs).

```
var entry = {
  quizzName : 'abc',
  quizzScore : 123
};

User.findOne({_id:id, function(err, object) {
  if(err) {
    return someErrorCallback();
  }
  var 
  object.quizzHistory.push(entry);
  object.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return someErrorCallback();
    }
    someSuccessCallback();
  });
});
```

Updating directly may be efficient, but questions usage of mongoose.

Hope it makes sense.